# Cursor Data not loading into the listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have written a fragment that loads up data from a custom content provider. I have used the cursor loader implementation from the contacts sample program from the google samples. The problem that I am currently facing is data is not being shown and is stuck at the loading screen from below.

[link](http://postimg.org/image/q1xx5vkp7/)

This is my fragment

```
public class DealsFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private static final String TAG = "DealsFragment";
private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

private DealsAdapter mAdapter;
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private DealInteractionListener mListener;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Uri uri = DealProvider.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
    //mAdapter = new DealCursorAdapter(getActivity(),c);
    //mAdapter = new DealListAdapter(getActivity());
    String[] columns = {DealProvider.ID,DealProvider.DEAL_DATA};
    int[] ids = {R.id.promotion_name,R.id.promotion_description};
    mAdapter = new DealsAdapter(getActivity());
    setEmptyText("No applications");
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    setListShown(false);

    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ Calling initLoader()! +++");
        if (getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID) == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "+++ Initializing the new Loader... +++");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "+++ Reconnecting with existing Loader (id '1')... +++");
        }
    }
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

public static DealsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    DealsFragment fragment = new DealsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */

public DealsFragment() {
}
void insertDeal(String data){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DealProvider.DEAL_DATA, data);
    Uri uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
            DealProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    Log.d(TAG,"DealInserted");
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    insertDeal("Hello World");
    try {
        mListener = (DealInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    final Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getCursor();

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mListener.onDealSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }
}



/**********************/
/** LOADER CALLBACKS **/
/**********************/


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = DealProvider.CONTENT_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Swapping with new cursor");
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}




/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface DealInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onDealSelected(String id);
}

private class DealsAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public DealsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null,0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View itemLayout =
                mInflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_list_item, parent, false);


        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.promotion_name);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.promotion_description);
        holder.img = (ImageView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        itemLayout.setTag(holder);
        return itemLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        final String data = cursor.getString(1);
        final int id = cursor.getInt(0);


        try {
            JSONObject deal = new JSONObject(data);
            String deal_name = deal.getString("deal_name");
            String deal_desc = deal.getString("deal_description");


            holder.text1.setText(deal_name);
           holder.text2.setText(deal_desc);

            String deal_url = deal.getString("deal_url");
            DownloadImageTask d = new DownloadImageTask(holder.img);
            d.execute(deal_url);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        return super.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }


}
```

and Content Provider

```
public class DealProvider extends ContentProvider {

static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.idisplay.frags.dealProvider";
static final String URL = "content://" +PROVIDER_NAME + "/deals";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);


// Creates a UriMatcher object.
//private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;

public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String DEAL_DATA = "deal_data";

static final int DEALS = 1;
static final int DEALS_ID = 2;


DBHelper dbHelper;

private static HashMap<String, String> DealMap;

static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static{
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "deals", DEALS);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "deals/#", DEALS_ID);
}

private SQLiteDatabase database;
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myapp";
static final String TABLE_NAME = "deals";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " deal_data TEXT NOT NULL);";

public DealProvider() {
//    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(0);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // Implement this to handle requests to delete one or more rows.
    int count = 0;

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case DEALS:
            // delete all the records of the table
            count = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case DEALS_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();   //gets the id
            count = database.delete( TABLE_NAME, ID +  " = " + id +
                    (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                            selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
//        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
//            // Get all friend-birthday records
//            case DEALS:
//                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.friends";
//            // Get a particular friend
//            case DEALS_ID:
//                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.friends";
//            default:
//                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
//        }
    return "";
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long row = database.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);

    // If record is added successfully
    if(row > 0) {
        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, row);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
        return newUri;
    }
    throw new SQLException("Fail to add a new record into " + uri);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = getContext();
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    // permissions to be writable
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if(database == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    // the TABLE_NAME to query on
    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        // maps all database column names
        case DEALS:
            queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(DealMap);
            break;
        case DEALS_ID:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere( ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(database, projection, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    /**
     * register to watch a content URI for changes
     */
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs) {
    int count = 0;

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case DEALS:
            count = database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case DEALS_ID:
            count = database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID +
                    " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment() +
                    (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                            selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri );
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}

private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)     {
        Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ". Old data will be destroyed");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what does the log cat say?

Comment: Nothing actually. There is a service that adds the data and this fragment shows that data. The logs show of data being added and cursor being changed. But the data is not showing up in the fragment. Its just showing loading O, and it stays there .

Comment: try running on a real device instead of emulator and see what happens.

Comment: I am running on a real device. Can you tell me if there is something wrong with getType() in provider? Can it return empty string or it needs to have a value?

Comment: it will return null if there is no string. It can return null.

Comment: Can you run this using an emulator add a break point where the loading process starts, so you will get the exact reason why this is happening.

Comment: Sorry I kinda copied the whole thing from that contacts adapter. The function setListShown(false) was not showing the list that is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function setListShown(false) was not showing the list that is being loaded.